# dropdown menu content issues/problems

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f1f1f1; 
  }

  .header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .header h1{
    font-size: 30px; 
  }
  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(52, 52, 52);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.753);
  }

  .drop {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .drop .dropbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
  }


  .navbar .a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size:  20px;
  }


  .navbar .a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }

  .drop-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .drop-content .a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

  }

  .drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .leftside {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .rightside {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  .fakeimg {
    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  div .fakeimg:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .card {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  .footer {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    margin-top: 20px;
  }


  /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .leftside, .rightside {   
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
  
  /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .navbar a {
      float: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    
</head>

<!--This is a link to the CSS.-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="first_webpage.css">

<body>

    
    <!--This is our header.-->
    
    <div>
        <header class="header">
            <h1>First Webpage</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

<!--This is a navigation bar.-->

    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Home</a>
        <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Contact</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                <i></i>
            </button>
                <div class="drop-content">
                    <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#" target="_self" class="a">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            
        </div>
        <a href="#" target="_self" class="a" style="float: right;">About</a>
    </div>

<!--This is the first and main colum.-->

    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="leftside">
            <div class="card">
                <h2>Title One</h2>
                <h5>Description, May 31, 2022</h5>
                    <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
                        <figcaption>Section 1.1 City</figcaption>
                            <p>This is subsection title</p>
                                <p>This is the first paragraph of the main section.
                                This also my first webpage. It definitly looks 
                                like something from the <i><a href="https://www.nytimes.com/">
                                New York Times</a></i>. It's coming out pretty good;
                                i just need to continue taking it one step at a time.
                                Nonetheless, I will contue on with this section and 
                                not bore you. Enjoy the rest of my layout.</p>
                  
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                 <h2>Title Two</h2>
                    <h5>Description, May 31, 2022</h5>
                        <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
                            <figcaption>Section 1.2 Flowers</figcaption>
                                <p>This is a second section Title</p>
                                <p>This is a second paragraph, I really don't know 
                                what to write. It's not like this is an engligh 
                                101 class. i mean jesus. Talking about jesus, do 
                                you know they're making a jesus game... i mean 
                                what has the gaming industry come to?</p>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rightside">
            
            <div class="card">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                    <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div>
                        <p>Some text about me so that the visiter may
                        know a bit more about the developer that they're 
                        interested in...</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Popular Posts</h3>
                    <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
                    <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
                    <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
                    <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Social Media</h3>
                    <p>Some social media pages that individuals can 
                    follow me on....</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--This is a footer-->

    <div class="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for my dropdown button; as I create the dropdown button everything seems to be fine, however, once I put the position to "absolute" it does not allow me to view the content that is within the dropdown button even when I'm hovering over it. I tried changing the position to anything other than "absolute" and it does allow me to view the content, but it would either stretch the navigation bar down to make room for the options or place the content lower than where the button is located. Can anyone help me out with this problem? I provided the full code for my html and CSS because I think it may be clashing with another code.

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.drop` to start with

Comment: Also `.drop` needs to be `position:relative`